# How can I unregister my user from my application?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook C# SDK in my application and using Graph API. Everything is working fine. However, I didn't get how to unregister my users from my application meaning revoke the rights given to my application.

I didn't get how to do this using SDK. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [user documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

> You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended
>   permissions on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to
>   PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token for that app.

Also, you can still call [auth.revokeAuthorization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeAuthorization/) or [auth.revokeExtendedPermission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeExtendedPermission/).